# Assets metadata: Matrix required?

Tags: assets, custom-fieldtype

I'd like to add very basic metadata to assets (Alttext, Caption..)

I noticed in volumes you can add custom field types – but they're not appearing when editing the entry. I found it can be edited in the assets view, but that's too complicated for editors.

If those values should be editable in the entry – should the matrix field type be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see an Asset, Entry, Category, or Tag (really, any type of "Element" in Craft), you can double-click the attached tile (in your case, the Asset thumbnail, in your Entry) to get an element editor modal.

This makes editing resources that are one-away much easier than finding it in its element index.

See below for an example:

[image: An example of an Element HUD in Craft 3]

> Two things to note: first, this does happen to be attached *inside* a Matrix field, but that's just coincidental—this same feature is available wherever you have a relation field (including other modals); second, I have no fields assigned to this Volume, so it's showing two standard fields, the Filename and Title. Your fields will appear below these.

Comment: Awesome! I‘ll see if I can add a comment to make it findable for editors and add a required field. Else I‘ll stick to matrix similar to what jon herra proposes

Comment: I'll stick to matrix – it's easier to understand for editors

Answer (score 2):

You could go for a lightweight content-builder. That would mean that you could and would create a matrix blocktype for each of your content elements i.e. one blocktype for image with all the metadata you could chew on as fields, another for say body with some props too and so forth.

That would also give your users some neat control over the document flow.

Then you would saw it seamlessly together on the template layer. Your Content-Editors will not feel a thing.